# Finding plane equation by using parametric equation

Tags: linear-algebra, parametric

Find the plane equation passing through $(4,-2,6)$

$x=3-2t$, $y=t$ and $z=5+2t$

How was the solution of these type of questions..Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the "reverse process" of this? https://mathinsight.org/plane_parametrization_examples

Comment: Also, you could just try **something** and see what happens. I think you will stumble upon the solution quite easily.

Comment: The plane is uniquely defined by $t$ and a point on the plane. You already have a given point, so have you tried finding $t$?

Comment: What grade are you in? High school or university?

Comment: first year student

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P(4,-2,6)$ and line $AB$: $X_\ell=A+t\,(B-A)=(3,0,5)+t\,(-2,1,2)$, then the plane equation will be $n\cdot (X-A)=0$ where $n=[(P-A)\times(B-A)]$ and $X=(x,y,z)$ an arbitrary point on the plane.
As the [mixed product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) corresponds to determinant, we have
$$\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
x-3&y&z-5\\
4-3&-2-0&6-5\\
-2&1&2
\end{array}
\right|=0$$
[$$-5 x - 4 y - 3 z + 30=0$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7Bx-3%2Cy%2Cz-5%7D%2C%7B4-3%2C-2-0%2C6-5%7D%2C%7B-2%2C1%2C2%7D%7D)
We can test now that $P$ and all the line $AB$ lies in the plane: WA results for [the point](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5+x+-+4+y+-+3+z+%2B+30%2C+x%3D4%2C+y%3D-2%2C+z%3D6) and [the line](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-5+x+-+4+y+-+3+z+%2B+30%2C+x%3D3%E2%88%922t%2C+y%3Dt%2C+z%3D5%2B2t) although it's not needed.

Answer (score 4):

We are given one point in the plane $(4,-2,6)$.  Two other points can be obtained by taking parameter $t=0$ and $t=1$ on the line:  $(3,0,5)$ and $(1,1,7)$.  Three non-collinear points determine a plane.  One way to find it is to take the cross product of two difference vectors:  $(1,-1,1)\times(3,-3,-1)=(5,4,3)$ is a normal vector to the plane.  Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

The generic equation of a plane is $\pi : ax + by + cz + d = 0$. This generic plane $\pi$ is parallel to the plane $ W_{\pi} : ax + by + cz = 0 $.

You can write $W_{\pi}$ as $Span\{(1,-2, 1), (-2, 1, 2)\}$, where $(1,-2, 1)$ is the vector $\vec{PQ}$, where $P(4, -2, 6)$ is the given point and $Q(3, 0, 5)$ is a point in the given line (obtained by taking $t = 0$), and $(-2,1,2)$ is the direction of the line.

We can write $Span\{(1,-2, 1), (-2, 1, 2)\}$ as:

$$\begin{cases}
x = t - 2s \\ 
y = -2t + s \\ 
z = t + 2s
\end{cases}
$$

after some steps you'll find the cartesian equation $5x+4y+3z = 0$, which corresponds to $ax+by+cz = 0$. To find $d$ we solve $5x+4y+3z + d = 0$ substituting to $x$, $y$ and $z$ the coordinates of $P$. This way you can find the equation $5x+4y+3z -30 = 0$ of the plane $\pi$, parallel to $W_{\pi}$ and containing the point $P$.

Comment: thanks for this type of solution!